# Inequality of supremum

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum, hahn-banach-theorem

I am going trough a funtional analysis course and to prove the geometric form of the Hahn-Banach theorem we need to prove that

> $\sup_ { \ b \in B } f(b) < \sup_ { \ b \in B \\ \|x\| < \epsilon.} f(b+x)$

We are in a normed space X, B is a convex subset of X and $f : X\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a linear funtion

Honestly im stuck in this step, I guess that I have to use the definition of norm of a functional (wich is $\|f\|=
\left\{|f(x)| \ \ x \in X \mid \|x\| = 1 \right\} $)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess the set $B$ is bounded.

Comment: Hint: Look at sequences $b_n\in B$ such that $\sup_{b\in B} f(b) = \lim_n f(b_n)$ and sequences $x_n$ s.t. $\| x_n \| =1$ and $\lim_n f(x_n) = \|f\|$.  Use linearity of $f$.

Comment: It seems that you have to assume that $\sup_{b\in B} f(b) < \infty.$